# Auto Download Attachments and Rename using Sender's Name

Tags: vba, outlook

I have the following code that auto save the attachments from any incoming mail and renames the attachment with the date and time so as not to overwrite.

```
Public Sub AutoSaveAttachment(itm As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
Dim dateFormat
    saveFolder = "C:\temp"
    dateFormat = Format(Now, "mm.dd.yyyy (Hh.Nn)")
        For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
            If InStr(objAtt.DisplayName, ".pdf") Then
            objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & "Attch " & dateFormat & "." & "pdf"
        End If
      Set objAtt = Nothing
    Next
End Sub
```

I want to add the sender's name before the date/time. I tried this code below which doesn't work. Run-time error.

```
Sub AttachmentDownloader(itm As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
Dim senderName As String
Dim dateFormat
    dateFormat = Format(Now, "mmddyyyy_(Hh.Nn)")
    senderName = objAtt.senderName & "_"
    saveFolder = "C:\temp"

     For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
            If InStr(objAtt.DisplayName, ".pdf") _
            Or InStr(objAtt.DisplayName, ".xlsx") _
            Or InStr(objAtt.DisplayName, ".xlsm") _
            Or InStr(objAtt.DisplayName, ".doc") _
            Or InStr(objAtt.DisplayName, ".docx") Then
         objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & senderName & dateFormat & objAtt.DisplayName

    End If
       Set objAtt = Nothing
    Next
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what's the runtime error and which line raises the error? (see [ask])

Comment: This line gives the run-time error  senderName = objAtt.senderName & "_". David figured it out.Thank you everyone. I was hung up on this for a bit.

Comment: Yep I guessed that much. see answer below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Runtime error "424: Object Required" because you haven't assigned to the `objAtt` variable yet. You've got an instantiated, but unassigned object variable.

Which is presumably an `Attachment` object, but that will raise a "Method or data member not found" error, because the  [*attachment* object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/attachment-object-outlook) doesn't have a `senderName` property, that belongs to the [`MailItem` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-object-outlook).

So, try:

```
senderName = itm.senderName & "_"
```